# 2 ELBs (ALBs) to 1 target group, possible?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, aws-cli

I have the following scheme:

> Internet <-> elb1external <-> varnish <-> elb2internal <-> targetgroupofwebnodes

But some `/static/*` & `/media/*` are routed to `targetgroupofwebnodes` from `elb1external` directly, around `varnish` & second ELB, so I need both `elb1` & `elb2` to point to the same target group of web nodes.

The Amazon web console shows the group as grayed out, when I try to select it from the drop down on the second ELB, but I do see mentioning of that scheme being possible on the web.

As a workaround I've created `targetgroupofwebnodes2` with the same servers in it, but I'm required to have only 1 & the next task is autoscaling, so there's going to be an autoscaling group instead of target group.

Must I use the CLI for that or there's a way through the web console?

Comment: You can targeting 2 ALB (or more) to 1 target group, but you can't chain two  ELB/ALB (like in your description) in any case.

Maybe explain more about your requirement other than the solution so others able to help you with a possible way to solve it

Comment: It looks like you can't point 2 ALBs to 1 target group (that's actually what I need) according to Amazon doc: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-limits.html **Load balancers per target group: 1**

Answer (score 23):

I'm not sure if you can point two ALBs to a single TargetGroup. However since you mentioned AutoScaling you **can** have the ASG instances automatically registered in more than one TargetGroups, therefore your approach with two target groups will work just as well with AutoScaling.

Hope that helps.

#### UPDATE #1

The OP was able to find this link to AWS docs on limits titled: [Limits for Your Application Load Balancers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-limits.html). In this docs on limits the number of target groups per ALB is mentioned in this table:

> Target Group Limits
>
> - Load balancers per target group: 1
> - Targets per target group (instances or IP addresses): 1000
> - Targets per target group (Lambda functions): 1

Based on this info, you cannot have the same target group in more than one ALB.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've actually figured it out myself while playing with auto scaling groups. Two ALBs can't be pointed to a single Target Group & it's strange: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-limits.html **Load balancers per target group: 1**

Comment: @GTXBxaKgCANmT9D9 if the answer is correct please upvote and accept it to reward the reputation points for the effort taken answering your question. Thanks!

Comment: The linked AWS docs do not contain the "Load balancers per target group" limit anymore. Does this mean it is now possible?

Comment: @FlorianvonStosch afaik, conceptually it is not possible to have more than 1 LB per TG. It's a 1:1 relationship. I also find it confusing.